# data currect user on firebase android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I try to do an app with Android Studio but I have a question and need help.

if I entered to the application with user - for example the user levana(i login to levana user with email and password)

and now I want to know my current user information (like email,firstname, password) how I do that? and what to write?
and more question, if I want to know if levana is a kind of 'Help' user how I do that? and what to write?

thanks

i add picture to this question, and there is no need code because i see that i need only to work with commands declarations and function of firebase and database

[image]

edit :

```
    DatabaseReference db = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference emailRef =db.child("Users").child("Help").child(FireLog.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replaceAll("\\.", ","));
    Log.e("Stringvalueschec", "" +emailRef.toString());
    DatabaseReference emailRef = db.child("Users").child("Help").child(FireLog.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replaceAll("\\.", ","));
    Log.e("Stringvalueschec", "" +emailRef.toString());

 
   Log.e("Stringvalueschec", "" +emailRef);

    emailRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();

                Configs.Pref_Email=snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                Configs.Pref_Email_Commas=snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class).replaceAll("\\.", ",");;
                Configs.Pref_First_Name= snapshot.child("firstName").getValue(String.class);
                Configs.Pref_Last_Name= snapshot.child("lastName").getValue(String.class);
                Configs.Pref_Phone=snapshot.child("Phone").getValue(String.class);
                Configs.Pref_Password= snapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);


                Log.e("Stringvalueschec", "" + Pref_Email + " " + Pref_Email_Commas + " " + Pref_First_Name + " " + Pref_Last_Name  + " " + Pref_Phone+ " " + Pref_Password);



            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is not so clear to me, but exactly do you want to achieve? Do want only to read the data under levana@gmail,com node?

Comment: Yes exactly,i want all the data on the object email of levana ,  and to get the parent Help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, to get the data under `levana@gmail,com`, you have to create a reference that points exactly to the `levana@gmail,com` node and attach a listener on it. So please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference emailRef = db.child("Users").child("Help").child("levana@gmail,com");
emailRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", email); //Will print levana@gmail.com
            String firstName = snapshot.child("firstName").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", firstName); // Will print levana
            String lastName = snapshot.child("lastName").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", lastName); // Will print ezra
            String password = snapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", password); // Will print 123123
            String parent = snapshot.getRef().getParent()
            Log.d("TAG", parent); // Will print Help
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks you , but i mean if i dont know that i in levana specific user ,i mean like i enter to random user and i dont know who is the user email i entered , so how i get the details from him ?

Comment: With a random user, it's not gonna work. You can do a double iteration through the "Users" node, but without having a user detail, or any user detail, you cannot get that.

Comment: So you should make your own attempt given the information in the last comment and if have a hard time implementing it, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: maybe with something like String email = auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(); i can get myemail and after that to do  DatabaseReference emailRef = db.child("Users").child("Help").child("levana@gmail,com"); it will work ?  @Alex Mamo

Comment: Yes, it will. But please note that it will work only if the user is authenticated, ok? The correct reference should be `DatabaseReference emailRef = db.child("Users").child("Help").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());`.

Comment: when i do this i get null but why ? (i edit the post up)

Comment: ok i know what my problem . i need to upload this details on real time and because of that i get null , thx